# Is using ANALYZE in Airflow dags a leading practice/requirement

Tags: postgresql, airflow, amazon-rds

I'm using AWS, Postgresql RDS v 13.7 and Managed Airflow v2.4.3.

I have one task in my Airflow dag that takes forever to finish/hangs despite it only being 1m rows of input and output.  If I run analyze before running my task, the query only takes 10 seconds, as expected.

I reached out to AWS support and their recommendation was to add an ANALYZE before every task.  This guidance is new to me.  From this post, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/292642/when-to-analyze-columns, I understand postgres auto analyzes when table turnover is > 10%.  The table in question is updated every day and turnover is < 10%.

Is the appropriate guidance to check turnover and/or check/run a

```
SELECT schemaname, relname, last_autoanalyze, last_analyze FROM pg_stat_all_tables WHERE relname = '<table name>';
```

I'm familiar with regular analyze, vacuum, reindexing of my database to maintain health but running an analyze before every query is doubling my pipeline time.

Any guidance or references to documentation is appreciated.

What I tried and were expecting: Historically this task completes in less than 10 seconds.  I'd expect comparable performance since data size hasn't changed.  I tried cloning the table and running different parts of the query.  The same query on a cloned table behaves exactly as expected